# pointer to pointer address

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

I have a question about pointer to pointer.

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int num=10;
    int *numPtr1;
    int **numPtr2;

    numPtr1 = &num;
    numPtr2 = &numPtr1;
    printf("%d\n", num);
    printf("%d\n", *numPtr1);
    printf("%d\n", **numPtr2);
    printf("%p\n", &num);
    printf("%p\n", numPtr1);
    printf("%p", numPtr2);
}
```

Why numPtr2's address is not the same with numPtr1, numPtr2?
For example, let num's address 0x7fffaca780b4. Then when I run this code, the output is

```
10
10
10
0x7fffaca780b4
0x7fffaca780b4
0x7fffaca780b8
```

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Why don't you make `numPtr1` point at something else and run your program again.  Perhaps it will become clear.

Comment: `numPtr1` has the address of `num`, `numPtr2` has the address to `numPtr1`, thus `*numPtr2` is the address to `num`.

Comment: Most of these print statements are undefined behaviour and so are meaningless. The argument to `%d` must have type `int`. The argument to `%p` must have type `void *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numptr2` is pointing to numptr1 varible,numptr1 is pointing to num.
So in `numptr2` address of numptr1 will be stored & in `numptr1` address of num will be stored
both`(numptr1,num)` addresses are different.
this is the reason that the you get different address.

Answer (score 1):

`numPtr1` and `numPtr2` are two different variables.  So where those variables are located will be different, regardless of where they point to.

Answer (score 0):

> Why numPtr2's address is not the same with numPtr1, numPtr2?

Each variable has its own address in memory so their **content may be same** but their **address can't be same** otherwise it would be impossible to differentiate them.

Answer (score 0):

***About [num]***
value of [num] = 10
memory location of [num] = 0115FC14

***About [numPtr1]***
value of [numPtr1] when it dereferenced = 10
address of [numPtr1] is holding = 0115FC14
memory location of [numPtr1] = 0115FC08

***About [numPtr2]***
value of [numPtr2] when it dereferenced once = 0115FC14(*numPtr2)
value of [numPtr2] when it dereferenced twice = 10(**numPtr2)
address of [numPtr2] holding = 0115FC08(numPtr2) is equals to memory location of [numPtr1] = 0115FC08(&numPtr1)
memory location of [numPtr2] = 0115FBFC

| Name | num | numPtr1 | numPtr2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Value | 10 | 0115FC14 | 0115FC08 |
| Memory location | 0115FC14 | 0115FC08 | 0115FBFC |

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 5;
    int* a_ptr1 = &a;
    int** a_ptr2 = &a_ptr1;
    puts("***About [a]***");
    printf("value of [a] = %d\nmemory location of [a] = %p\n\n", a, &a);

    puts("***About [a_ptr1]***");
    printf("value of [a_ptr1] when it dereferenced = %d\n", *a_ptr1);
    printf("address of [a_ptr1] is holding = %p\n", a_ptr1);
    printf("memory location of [a_ptr1] = %p\n\n", &a_ptr1);

    puts("***About [a_ptr2]***");
    printf("value of [a_ptr2] when it dereferenced once = %p(*a_ptr2)\n", *a_ptr2);
    printf("value of [a_ptr2] when it dereferenced twice = %d(**a_ptr2)\n", **a_ptr2);
    printf("address of [a_ptr2] holding = %p(a_ptr2) ", a_ptr2);
    printf("is equals to memory location of [a_ptr1] = %p(&a_ptr1)\n", &a_ptr1);
    printf("memory location of [a_ptr2] = %p\n\n", &a_ptr2);


    printf("Name\t\t[a]<---------[a_ptr1]<-------[a_ptr2]\n");
    printf("Value\t\t%d            %p        %p\n", a, a_ptr1, a_ptr2);
    printf("Address\t\t%p     %p        %p\n", &a, &a_ptr1, &a_ptr2);

}
```